# Using /bin/false with vsftpd - how is it a security issue?

Tags: ssh, security, vsftpd

We are using `vsftpd` with allowed users file.

The `vsftpd` users use FTP (performance reasons), so passwords could be easily stolen.

`vsftpd` **"chroot"** option is enabled, so the users cannot go out of their homedirs.

There is also an `sshd` running, with **"pw auth enabled"**.

We set `/bin/false` as shell for the vsftpd users, to disable their login via **SSH**.

The question: how and what can someone do via **SSH**, if they steal the **pw**? Remote user, not local.

So far I read that it could use **"tcp forwarding"** (?), but that probably doesn't do any harm, I mean he couldn't get to the files on the server.

Could they use **SCP**, **SFTP** somehow? Or a non-interactive shell somehow?

Answer (score 0):

If possible, block SSH (TCP port 22) from the Internet. You'll have bots trying passwords all day long. If you have to have remote SSH access, consider using a VPN or at least putting SSH on a non-standard port and/or limiting what IP addresses can connect.

Changing the shell is a good first step, but you want to make sure they can't use any other features and jail them as much as possible. TCP forwarding is a pretty big issue. It's basically using the connection as a VPN and proxy, so the attacker would be in your network, behind your firewall. They could use that to attack your internal hosts or mount attacks from your network against others. If you're going to expose the SSH port, modify `sshd_conf` to reduce what they can do:

```
DenyGroups ftpusers               ....if they shouldn't SSH/SFTP at all

Match group ftpusers              ....whatever group you've assigned to the accounts
    AllowTcpForwarding no
    X11Forwarding no
    ForceCommand internal-sftp
    ChrootDirectory /home/ftpuser ....or some other safe place, like an empty folder.
```

The second option could be useful if you want them to SFTP but not SSH. Take a look at `man sshd_config` for match patterns.